# Weird behavior in Eclipse

Tags: 13.10, eclipse, ide, titlebar, menu-bar

The menu bar in eclipse isn't working! I tried removing and installing it again but no help.

In my other PC, running the same version of ubuntu (13.10), the menu bar is on the top of the window, not on the very top of the screen like in the screenshot

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Which version of Eclipse do you have installed?

Comment: The latest! just installed using apt-get

Comment: can you tell a step by step procedure to recreate it.maybe then we would be able to tell you the correct reason.also visit the eclipse website and check if a bug is reported there.

Comment: I got the answer, it's tagged duplicate.